# How to join two trees with forest/tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, forest

I beg your pardon if I make some mistakes, I'm fully new here.
I'm trying to do a presentation with Beamer about syntactic structures and I need to draw two trees. The second tree (which begins with ForceP) is a kind of zoom/split of a section of the first tree. I also need to link them with an arrow.

I've done it with two trees (drawn with forest) and a separate arrow with tikzpicture. Do you know how I can get it more precise? Perhaps using some anchors, tikzmark or labels in the trees? Thanks a lot!

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}

%------- CODIFICA ------------------------------------
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
%---- LINGUISTICA -----------------------------------
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,arrows.meta}
\usepackage{forest}
\useforestlibrary{linguistics}


\begin{document}
\forestset{
 xlist/.style={
 phantom,
 for children={no edge,replace by={[,append,
 delay={content/.wrap pgfmath arg={\csname @alph\endcsname{##1}.}{n()+##1}}
 ]}}
 },
 xlist/.default=0
 }
\begin{columns}
 \begin{column}{5cm}
 \begin{forest}
[CP,tikz={\node [draw,red,fit=()(!1)(AB)] {};}
[SpecCP] [C' [C$_0$] [IP,name=AB [SpecIP] [I' [I$_0$] [VP [,roof]]]]]]
\end{forest}
\end{column}

\begin{column}{5cm}
\begin{forest}
[ForceP,tikz={\node [draw,red,fit to=tree] {};}
  [SpecForce] 
[Force' [Force$_0$] 
[\ldots [FinP [SpecFin] 
[Fin' [Fin$_0$] [IP [,roof]]]
]]]]
\end{forest}
 \end{column}
\end{columns}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
 \draw [-Latex, red] (2.80,5) [out=75, in=230]to (5.9,4);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Here my result]

Comment: You don't seem to be using the `xlist` style?

Comment: When you say 'more precise', what are you looking to do exactly? You could draw the two trees as one, by using a `phantom` root. This can be done with `forest` alone. (Well, of course, it is using `tikz` and so on, but I mean that you don't need anything additional.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest solution may be to use a `phantom` root and draw both trees as one.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,beamer]{standalone}
\usepackage[linguistics]{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Two in One}
  \centering
  \begin{forest}
    [, phantom, for children={fit=band}, s sep'+=20pt
      [CP, name=CP
        [SpecCP]
        [C'
          [C$_0$]
          [IP, name=AB
            [SpecIP]
            [I'
              [I$_0$]
              [VP
                [,roof]
              ]
            ]
          ]
        ]
      ]
      [ForceP, tikz+={
        \node (fit1) [draw, red, fit to={name=CP,1,name=AB}] {};
        \node (fit2) [draw, red, fit to=tree] {};
        \draw [-Latex, red] (fit1.east) [out=75, in=230]to (fit2.west);
      }
        [SpecForce
        ]
        [Force'
          [Force$_0$]
          [\ldots
            [FinP
              [SpecFin]
              [Fin'
                [Fin$_0$]
                [IP
                  [,roof]
                ]
              ]
            ]
          ]
        ]
      ]
    ]
  \end{forest}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: two in one]